# Unresolved error while executing Drake Shoe Tie example

Tags: drake

I'm getting following error while running the example as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/gym/tree/master/gym/envs/robot_locomotion_group/drake/shoe) link:

```
from gym.envs.robot_locomotion_group.drake.shoe.open_loop import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym.envs.robot_locomotion_group'
```

Can someone please tell why so, when this file exists.

Also, after installation of drake, I couldn't locate any file under /opt to run Drake-visulaizer as
`/opt/drake/bin/drake-visualizer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should check if `gym` is inside your `PYTHONPATH`. If you're not running an IDE / virtual environment, you should append the git folder to `PYTHONPATH`. For example, add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file,

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/{USERNAME}/gym:${PYTHONPATH}`

and afterwards, don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc`.

The more serious problem is that this package is very out-of-date and not maintained anymore. A lot has happened since it was written:

- Drake has deprecated `drake-visualizer`, and now solely supports `meshcat`.
- A variety of syntax within Drake has changed, so running this code with the current version of Drake will produce many errors.
- I think the RL folks are moving `gym` to `gymnasium`, so the version of `gym` that `RobotLocomotion/gym` uses should be deprecated as well.

I managed to fix the second issue for you and just pushed a hotfix to main that makes the code compatible with the current version of Drake. If you pull from main again and run

`python3 gym/envs/robot_locomotion_group/drake/shoe/test_gym.py`

it should be running. You'll see a text like

`INFO:drake:Meshcat listening for connections at http://localhost:7001` where you can click on the link to open the meshcat visualizer.

But going forwards, I would take the environments within `gym/envs/robot_locomotion_group/drake` and use it separately outside of gym for your project.